# Dialogflow fulfillment chose among options

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am writing you to ask a question about Dialogflow fulfillments.

I am trying to create an agent for Google Home and my backend is basically a web hook implemented in TypeScript.

In the conversation that I designed, the user requests to the agent to perform an action, providing a **category** as paramter. Now, the set of possible categories can vary through time, so I am using the entity type *@sys.any* to detect the parameter.

My problem is that, when on the fulfillment I try to identify the specific category on which the agent needs to take action, it may be the case that the requested paramter matches **multiple cateogries**, so I'd need a followup intent to ask the user to clarify which is the actual category it wants to select.

E.g. the conversation could be the following:

```
Agent: 'Welcome.'
User:  'Do action on **category**'
Agent: 'I have found **categoryA**, **categoryB** and **categoryC**. Please specify which one you want to select.'
User:  'Select the second || Select **categoryB**'
Agent: 'Great, action performed on **categoryB**'
```

Now, I was able to build this conversation using followup events and contexts: for example I created two followup events, one that detects the numbers and another that detects the text, so the user is driven on one or another depending on what it says (if the user says 'The first', a number is detected and in the backend I cycle the categories selecting the one that is associated to that index. I do a similar operation if the user says "categoryX", but inside a different intent).

What I want to understand is: what is the proper way to achieve that kind of conversation through the Node.js fulfillment API?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you check https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/userentities, using the POST service you can save the entities when user connects to the bot and using an intent and slot filter you can have any category with respect to the current session.

While creating a slot filtering for an intent create a custom user defined datatype.

Do action on **category** , create an entry name as `user_category` and make your utterance **category** as `user_category`. While user connects to bot save all the possible category related to user using the API.

Answer (score 1):

From your description - you've done precisely the right thing (although you don't need followup intents).

When you reply with the options the user has, you include a Context that may contain the array of possible results. You then create Intents that have this as an Input Context, match either the index of the array (lets call this the match.index Intent) or by name (the match.name Intent).

In your webhook, the match.index Intent would determine which category was actually chosen, and then call a function that takes care of that category. Similarly, the webhook for match.name would take the parameter with the name and call the same function to take care of that category.